# Broadcast not triggering

Tags: android

I have been teaching myself android programming and I've run up against a problem with broadcasts. Essentially this code is just me testing to see if I can get broadcasts to work. When I run it my broadcast is not called and I'm not sure why.

Here is the relevant bit of manifest

```
 <reciever
        android:name="application.logic.StartEventReciever"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_event" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Set Start Alarm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </reciever>
```

Here is my BroadcastReciever

```
  public class StartEventReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.v("@StartEvent", "BOO");

   }
 }
```

And here is the bit where I make the intent. It's a part of a larger static class I've been using.

```
public static void setStartAlarm(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent("Set Start Alarm");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<reciever` tag is spelled wrong. It is `<receiver> </receiver>`

Comment: fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu

Thanks!